# How to make a condition that if a value (that is a character) starts with a specific word, then I need to print a vector?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, character

I have this dataframe that I applied `ifelse` function and `startsWith` function

```
df = data.frame(x = c('part1',letters[1:3],'part2',letters[5:6]))

y = 5:6

df$y = ifelse(startsWith(df$x,'part'),y,NA)
df
```

However the output is

```
      x  y
1 part1  5
2     a NA
3     b NA
4     c NA
5 part2  5
6     e NA
7     f NA
```

The column y includes 5 and 5 instead of 5 and 6. I don't know what the error is I am making. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I guess the problem is about recycling. With `ifelse`, you have 5, 6, 5, 6 and NA are filled. With `[` indexing before, the assignment is done *only* on the `part` values

Comment: ah sorry it is in French. It means that 3 variables are provided to replace 1 variable

Comment: it's ok and thank you. will delete the comments to not distract the readers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifelse` probably isn't the right tool here.

If you want a one-liner solution in base R you could use `replace`:

```r
within(df, y <- replace(rep(NA, nrow(df)), startsWith(df$x, 'part'), y))
#>       x  y
#> 1 part1  5
#> 2     a NA
#> 3     b NA
#> 4     c NA
#> 5 part2  6
#> 6     e NA
#> 7     f NA
```

Although I guess most folks would probably just create an `NA` column and write `y` into the matching indices.

```r
df$y <- NA
df$y[startsWith(df$x, 'part')] <- y

df
#>       x  y
#> 1 part1  5
#> 2     a NA
#> 3     b NA
#> 4     c NA
#> 5 part2  6
#> 6     e NA
#> 7     f NA
```

Both approaches of course assume that the number of matches is the same as the length of `y`, and you probably need some extra logic to check that this is definitely the case.

<sup>Created on 2022-11-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>